# I want to output the animated image on React Native View to the phone's gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making a photo editor application. In this application, GIF can be added to the photo, but I cannot save the added GIF with the image to the phone. Do you know of a library for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have already configured the
[fresco](https://frescolib.org/docs/index.html).

```
dependencies {

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0'
}
```

Comment: My purpose is not to view, I have no problem with that, I want to print